# Obter Consumos Baixos num Raio de 100m?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocalização, coordenadas

Tenho uma base de dados com consumo e coordenadas em Excel, do tipo:

[image: Consumo e Coordenada]

Neste sentido, preciso de escrever um código que me permita encontrar, de local para local, consumos inferiores à média de consumos dentro de um raio de 100m.
Pretende-se que o raio de 100m seja calculado não uma vez, mas sim para cada par de coordenadas.

código usado:

```
R9 = []
R9_NaN = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    coord_1 = (row['X'], row['Y'])
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        coord_2 = (row['X'], row['Y'])
        if coord_2 != coord_1:
            dist = geopy.distance.geodesic(coord_1, coord_2).km
            if dist <= 0.100:
                média=sum((row['Consumo2018']/12)/(len(coord_2)+1))
                if row['Consumo2018']/12 < 1.5*média:
                    R9_NaN.append(index)
                    R9.append(0)
                else:
                    R9.append(0)

print(R9)
```

O geopy.distance é uma livraria que já calcula a distância entre duas coordenadas.

No código acima; a "média" é suposto que seja a média do consumo de locais dentro do raio de 100m que também deve variar de local para local.

Está a dar-me este erro:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: Você jé tem algum código ou uma tabela que consiga, através das coordenadas descobrir qual a distancia em M de uma coordenada a outra ?

Comment: eu tenho a fórmula matemática pra descobrir isso mas não o código em python, apesar que está bem facil entender esse código java e todos os métodos utilizados você encontra dentro da biblioteca math do python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837872/calculate-distance-in-meters-when-you-know-longitude-and-latitude-in-java

Comment: para descobrir qual a distancia em M de uma coordenada para a outra uso a livraria geopy.

Comment: Você está chamando a função `sum` passando apenas um valor numérico como parâmetro. Não faz muito sentido somar um número apenas. Se você já possui o consumo de 2018 e o número de registros, a média não seria apenas a divisão? O que precisa somar aqui?

Comment: aqui é apenas suposto somar os consumos dos locais dentro do raio de 100m; estou a usar o row, no propósito que ele faça a soma de todos esses valores...